# What does the _, do in this context. (Python / Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django

I've been racking my brain for the past 30 minutes trying to figure out what underscore and comma do in the following code, right before declaring filenames:

```
def list_entries():
"""
Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
"""
_,filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")

return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
            for filename in filenames if (filename.endswith(".md") and filename != ("EntryNotFound.md"))))
```

I know that an underscore can be used as a throwaway variable or to store the last variable called. But I cant see how that makes sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `os.listdir`, [Django storage's `listdir` returns a tuple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.listdir), the first entry of which is a list of directories, and the second of which is a list of files. The underscore is being used as a throwaway variable here, as you mentioned.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a throwaway variable that is used for [*iterable unpacking* [PEP-3132]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). If the `listdir` function returns an iterable with two elements, the first one will be assigned to the `_` variable, and the second to the `filenames`. Examples of such iterables are 2-tuples, lists with two items, strings with two characters, etc.

In this specific case, the [**`.listdir(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.listdir) returns a 2-tuple:

> **`listdir(path)`**
>
> Lists the contents of the specified path, returning a **2-tuple of
> lists**; the first item being directories, the **second item being
> files**. For storage systems that aren’t able to provide such a
> listing, this will raise a `NotImplementedError` instead.

This thus means that we unpack the 2-tuple, assign the list of directories to the `_` variable, and the list of the files to the `filenames` variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Sequence unpacking is being used here to grab the second item while "throwing away" the first. It would be essentially equivalent to:

```
stuff = default_storage.listdir("entries")
filenames = stuff[1]
del stuff  # This could be omitted
```

The underscore is being used because something must be there in order to name the second element via unpacking, but the first value unpacked isn't needed.